# How can I create phase shift (in degress) of analog filters in Pspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, spice, active-filter, pspice

How can I create phase shift of filters in Pspice? (like red curve)
[image]

also measure the delay at the output for a band pass filter created cascaded amplifiers.

Comment: What is the meaning of "wanna"?

Comment: "I want " meaning , sorry if ı used wrong word

Comment: Why are Vout1 and Vout2 "shorted ...

Comment: Good question, I do not connect it for this type of filter, but ti filter pro filter shows connection in this way. Is there an answer?

Comment: See this https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa1632.pdf?ts=1707048321708&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F or this https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4945-1.pdf

Comment: I knew its a fully differential amplifier and lowpass multiple feedback differential butterworth second order . Why are the outputs connected? –

Comment: It seems to be an error https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/769715/webench-tools-filterpro-filter-design-based-on-fully-differential-amplifier   <<< Note there is an error in the FDA filter circuit schematics shown in FilterPro. The schematics show the two FDA outputs shorted together. Remove the wire connected between the two FDA outputs in the actual circuit. If the short is not removed between the FDA outputs active filters will not work correctly. >>>

Comment: oh yes Antonio I separate it in all the pcbs I design. Ti filter pro calculates the values correctly but displays them incorrectly in the topology connection. Thank you for confirming.However, I'm still wondering how I can simulate phase shift in pspice. The filter in this image is just an example. Phase shift of all filters.

Comment: Phase shift is a "simple" command in PSPICE ... "Delay" is the "differential" function of "phase shift/frequency" = dphi/df.